# Is possible to have cloud run with load balancer on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'd like to use GCP Cloud Run with Loadbalancer, however, I haven't found a way to create a backend service or something to connect them. I found a way of using Anthos, but, I'd prefer without it.

`https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke`

How is that possible?, What more options are there?

Comment: Not possible today with the managed version. But it's going to be possible. No timeline for now. Stay tuned!

Comment: Agree with guillaume. Serverless backends for GCLB are coming soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this integration is possible with Serverless Network Endpoint [07-09-2020].

This is in beta, however, it looks pretty nice:

Concepts:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts

Setting:
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs

Comment: What about using multiple cloud run service in the same NEG?. I think the load balancer cant add different NEGs (each pointing to different cloud run services of the same region), am I wrong?